# App crashes when running build configuration : release ( Xcode )

Tags: xcode, react-native

So I created an iOS app and wanted to test it by running it (build configuration set to release) on a simulator. This returns this error:

Thread 6: "Unhandled JS Exception: Error: Requiring unknown module "./locale/1"., js engine: hermes, stack:\nunknownModuleError@166:16\nloadModuleImplementation@138:30\nguardedLoadModule@81:46\nmetroRequire@37:91\nloadLocale@158311:24\ngetLocale@158421:27\nlocale@159594:33\nRowMatch@156807:98\ncMatch@156490:63\nrenderItem@156533:21\nrender@29368:29\nrenderProp@29392:25\n_renderElement@32951:27\nrender@32975:41\nfinishClassComponent@20128:127\nupdateClassComponent@20120:31\nbeginWork$1@22002:211\nperformUnitOfWork@21650:26\nworkLoopSync@21644:54\nrenderRootSync@21630:18\nperformSyncWorkOnRoot@21405:35\nflushSyncCallbacks@18623:32\nflushPassiveEffects@21861:28\nanonymous@21712:25\nJ@17189:19\nR@17220:13\nanonymous@9533:25\n_callTimer@9461:16\n_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@9485:16\ncallReactNativeMicrotasks@9645:43\n__callReactNativeMicrotasks@2587:45\nanonymous@2477:44\n__guard@2571:14\nflushedQueue@2476:20\ninvokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@2470:32\n"

So I started running it, because when tested in TestFlight the app crashes immediately on launch.
Xcode returns this as an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.